# Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined

Tags: c#, wpf

When try to execute it give an error. in my stand alone application

hare is my code

```
var uri = new Uri(@"Earnest_Indieiduals/image/qty15section3.jpg");
                qestion15.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

error   Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use

```
var uri = new Uri(@"image/qty15section3.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```

in case code you are trying to execute is written in assembly Earnest_Indieiduals.

Also you can use [**Pack URI's**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/image/qty15section3.jpg",
                   UriKind.Absolute);
```

Comment: Great also you can refer to Pack URI's provided link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
var uri = new Uri("/Earnest_Indieiduals;component/image/qty15section3.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
qestion15.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

or

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/image/qty15section3.jpg")
qestion15.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```